# Implementing columnar encryption technique?

Tags: java

I am working on another encryption technique now, the columnar transposition cipher technique.
So far I have only tried to make columns and what I am trying to do is to view the matrix.
But with the code that I have written it is only showing one letter in the matrix:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class transCip {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String keys;
        String message;
        String encrypt;
        String decrypt;
        message = "encryptiontextbe";
        keys = "work";
        encrypt = "";
        decrypt = "";
        char msg[] = message.toCharArray();
        char key[] = keys.toCharArray();
        int x = msg.length;
        int y = key.length;
        char temp[][] = new char[y][x];

        if (x % y != 0) {
            System.out.println("Cannot encrypt string");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (x/y); i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) 
            {
                int k=0;
                temp[i][j] = msg[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Matrix");
        for (int i = 0; i < (x/y); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print(temp[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

And my current output is as follows:

```
Matrix
eeee
eeee
eeee
eeee
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening;
I tried solving the run on paper also.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: I am trying to implement columnar transposition cipher. As of now, i have only tried to break the string into columns according to the key. the first for loop breaks the string into columns. the second for loop is to print the matrix thus generated.

Comment: On another hand, you should not be using `System.out.println("");` either - it invokes a less efficient method `PrintStream.println(String)` which consumes your arbitrary empty literal String. Use `System.out.println();` instead.

Comment: okay..thanks..i'll make the required changes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < (x/y); i++) 
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) 
        {
        int k=0;
                temp[i][j] = msg[k];
        k++;
        }
        }
```

You reset k to zero in each iteration of the loop, guaranteeing you always get the first letter 'e' of your message string.  Try initializing k before the inner loop.  This would have been easier to spot with better formatting:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (x/y); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        int k=0;
        temp[i][j] = msg[k];
        k++;
    }
}
```